# Select nearest element by class on the same(or not) level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How to select the **nearest** element with a specific `class` that is **or** may not be on the same level as the clickable element?

For example, lets says that this is the output:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change D</p>
            </div>
            <p class="change-on-click">D</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change E</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="change-on-click">E</p>
</div>
```

I want when I click on `p.click` that it will find the nearest `p.change-on-click` element.

---

Just like this, but unfortunately I **can't** change the *HTML*.

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.change-on-click').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change D</p>
            </div>
            <p class="change-on-click">D</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change E</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="change-on-click">E</p>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle with the second situation](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/4ofajqxa/2)

Comment: I don't know what to do other than a parents recursion check...

Comment: @Verhaeren the fiddle is a *"usually, I would do that, but i can't change the HTML"* thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to require a custom approach since the jQuery API does not support that type of searching. Basically, just iterate through the parent nodes until you find the click-on-change element.

```js
$('.click').click(function(){
  var node = this;
  while(node != document.body){
   var target = $(node).find('.change-on-click')
   if( target.length == 0 ){
    node = node.parentNode;
   }else{
    target.css('color','red');
    return;
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! It works like a charm. I never thought that JQuery wouldn't have a selector for a situation like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
$('p.click').each(function(i){
    $(this).on("click", function(){$('.change-on-click').eq(i).css('color', 'red');});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ofajqxa/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? ( *Locate the target element via a while loop* )

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    var coc = $(this);
    while( !coc.prev().is( '.change-on-click' ) ) {
        coc = coc.parent();
    }
    coc.prev().css('color','red');
});
```

```js
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    var coc = $(this);
    while( !coc.prev().is( '.change-on-click' ) ) {
        coc = coc.parent();
    }
    coc.prev().css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OR**
(*Using a jQuery plugin*)

```js
$('p.click').on('click', function(){
    $(this).changeOnClick();
});

$.fn.changeOnClick = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var near = $(this);
    while( !near.prev().is('.change-on-click') ) {
      near = near.parent();
    }
    near.prev().css('color','red');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The following version should work for cases where the target element is before or after the clicked element:

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    var coc = $(this);
    while( !coc.prev().is( '.change-on-click' ) && !coc.next().is( '.change-on-click' ) ) {
        coc = coc.parent();
    }
    coc.prev().add( coc.next() ).filter( '.change-on-click' ).css('color','red');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6c59h9eb/1/)

Comment: I love the plugin! However, this won't work if the `.change-on-click` elements is **after** the `.click` element (tried to post the fiddle but the JS breaks it).

Comment: Glad you found something good here :) Thanks! Just to help me re-write the code for future generations, do you have a sample of a case where the `.change-on-click` element is after the `.click` element?

Comment: Sure, [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/6c59h9eb/) - I added aditional two cases.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Vucko. I have updated my answer and included a demo. Great question!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery without making extra functions and stuff like this...

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    $('.change-on-click', $(this).parents('div')).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">A</p>
        <p class="click">Click on this will change A</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">B</p>
        <div>
            <p class="click">Click on this will change B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <p class="change-on-click">C</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change C</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change D</p>
            </div>
            <p class="change-on-click">D</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class="click">Click on this will change E</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="change-on-click">E</p>
</div>
```